# How to find all web crawler's in a .log file

Tags: java, web-crawler

I need help. I need to find out how to find all web crawlers that are in a .log file. I have no idea what to look for. I know that a web crawler does something specific but I can't find a good way to program in java. Thanks

Comment: If you have luck the web crawler won`t spoof the [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_spoofing). If not, there is no feasable way to diferent a user browser from a crawler.

Comment: @PeterMmm Ususally, the peers IP gets checked against a list of "well known bots addresses" like Google or Bing e.a. but that's a nightmare to program and re-inventing the wheel anyway: Google Analytics will do for nothing.

Comment: Yepp, but sometimes, Googlebot plays "Firefox" to look whether people are doing seo spaming etc ...

Comment: I am given like the IP address and user agents ( I think) and every once in a while you will see like  Googlebot/2.(+http://www.google.com/bot.html) ...with all sorts of other different crawlers. Is there something unique like a pattern they all do.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a list of "official" User Agent strings of various web crawlers and exclude them from the log. The list is available [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

But remember, any bot or crawler can replace its User Agent in order to be identified as a common user.